# Converting MS Access calculated columns to MySQL

Tags: mysql, ms-access

I'm working on converting MS Access queries to MySQL. So far, I've been having good luck with it but I'm running into trouble with converting the below listed calculated columns in Access to MySQL:

1. IIf(sumofpacking Is Null,Bags,Bags-sumofpacking) AS Bags_Undelivered
2. IIf(sumofnet_qty Is Null,Lbs,Lbs-SumOfNET_QTY) AS Lbs_Undelivered
3. DateDiff("m", DELVPERIOD_TO, Date()) AS Months_Late
4. Round((0.025*Lbs Undelivered*Months Late),2) AS Store_Fin_Charges

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First and second question

To start Mysql doesn't have an `Iif` function. So the first 2  will need to use another function called `case` and can be used the following way according to this [tutorial](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-case-statement/);

```
CASE  case_expression
   WHEN when_expression_1 THEN commands
   WHEN when_expression_2 THEN commands
   ...
   ELSE commands
END CASE;
```

so your query parts would become:

```
case 
when sumofpacking Is Null then Bags else Bags-sumofpacking end case AS Bags_Undelivered
```

and

```
case
when sumofnet_qty Is Null then Lbs else Lbs-SumOfNET_QTY end case AS Lbs_Undelivered
```

---

2. Third question

The `datediff` function in mysql only uses 2 inputs as taken from this [tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff_mysql.asp):

```
SELECT DATEDIFF('2014-11-30','2014-11-29') AS DiffDate
```

Taking into consideration that date you have to supply a date to the function, your query would become:

```
DateDiff(DELVPERIOD_TO, Date(now())) AS Months_Late
```

---

4. Last question

Not sure why the last, number 4 doesn't work, probably because it doesn't recognize the one of the fields.

Comment: The last one looks like it is simply missing the underscores in the column names.